# flex 4: item renderer with data provider from soap: cannot convert ir@194e5851 to mx.controls.listClasses.IListItemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

i'm trying to populate a `<mx:List>` with a dataProvider that i received from a soap request.
i get the following error when i try to achieve this:

`TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert AchivementsItemRenderer@1906a851 to mx.controls.listClasses.IListItemRenderer.
    at mx.controls::List/createItemRenderer()[E:\dev\gumbo_beta2\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\List.as:1987]
    at mx.controls::List/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::getMeasuringRenderer()[E:\dev\gumbo_beta2\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\List.as:1896]
    at mx.controls::List/commitProperties()[E:\dev\gumbo_beta2\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\List.as:911]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\gumbo_beta2\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7387]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()[E:\dev\gumbo_beta2\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:572]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\gumbo_beta2\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:700]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\gumbo_beta2\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1069]`

if i use that same dataProvider on a `<mx:Repeater>` it works without any problems.
what am i missing?

#### mxml file

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
`<mx:VBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
         xmlns:local="*" backgroundColor="#aabbcc" fontSize="11" creationComplete="init()">`
`

```
    public var soap:SoapMyService = new SoapMyService();
    [Bindable]

    public var myData:Array;

    public function handleSoapResult(event:GetMyResultEvent):void {
        myData=event.result;
    }

    public function updateData():void {
        soap.getData(528);  

    }

    public function init():void {           
        soap.addgetMyDataEventListener(handleSoapResult);
        updateData();

    }

]]>
```

`

```
<mx:List id="myList" height="157" width="160" 
                    itemRenderer="theItemRenderer" 
                    baseColor="#323232" dataProvider="{myData}" >

</mx:List>
    </mx:VBox>
```

#### item renderer

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
`<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
                xmlns:local="*">`

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State name="hovered"/>
    <s:State name="selected" />
</s:states>

<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout/>
</s:layout>

<s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle" paddingTop="0" paddingBottom="0">
           <mx:Image source="http://www.xpogames.com/{data.img}" width="50" height="40" alpha.hovered=".5"/>
    <s:Label text="{data.username}" color.hovered="0x1313cd" color.selected="0x000000" verticalAlign="bottom"/> 
</s:HGroup>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: What's the code look like where you are populating your list?

Comment: tomorrow i will be able to supply the code, for now i just fetch the data using web service (soap), i get the result as an array of objects and display them using the dataProvider parameter of the <mx:list> element.

Comment: I think the thing to look at specifically is going to be the itemRenderer code. You're data is probably going into the list just fine, but something about your itemRenderer is causing the fault, either the call to use the itemRenderer or the renderer itself, please post both when you get a chance.

Comment: i edited the main post and added code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved the issue by using `<s:List>` instead of `<mx:List>` and by inserting `event.result` into an `ArrayCollection`. thanks for your help! :)